# Gradle 7.3.3 run Junit unable to create TestEngine

Tags: gradle, junit, mockito, powermock

I am using Gradle 7.3.3, but require JUnit and PowerMock

I have configured settings.gradle as:

```
        version('spring', '5.3.15')
        alias('spring-test').to('org.springframework', 'spring-test').versionRef('spring')

        //https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit
        version('junit', '4.13.2')
        alias('junit').to('junit', 'junit').versionRef('junit')

        //https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core
        version('mockito', '3.12.4')
        alias('mockito').to('org.mockito', 'mockito-core').versionRef('mockito')

        //https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.powermock/powermock-api-mockito2
        version('powermock', '2.0.9')
        alias('powermock-api').to("org.powermock", "powermock-api-mockito2").versionRef('powermock')
        alias('powermock-api-support').to("org.powermock", "powermock-api-support").versionRef('powermock')
        alias('powermock-core').to("org.powermock", "powermock-core").versionRef('powermock')
        alias('powermock-module-junit4').to("org.powermock", "powermock-module-junit4").versionRef('powermock')
        alias('powermock-module-junit4-common').to("org.powermock", "powermock-module-junit4-common").versionRef('powermock')
        alias('powermock-reflect').to("org.powermock", "powermock-reflect").versionRef('powermock')

        bundle('test', ['junit', 'mockito', 'powermock-api', 'powermock-api-support', 'powermock-core', 'powermock-module-junit4', 'powermock-module-junit4-common', 'powermock-reflect', 'spring-test'])
```

And then in the module's build.gradle, I included this

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation libs.bundles.test
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Test class is as below

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class MyTest {

    @Test
    public void test(){
        System.out.print("hello");
    }
}
```

After running the test, I get the report for the failing test with the following stacktrace

```
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.TestSuiteExecutionException: Could not complete execution for Gradle Test Executor 6.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$3.run(TestWorker.java:193)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:133)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:71)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
Caused by: org.junit.platform.commons.PreconditionViolationException: Cannot create Launcher without at least one TestEngine; consider adding an engine implementation JAR to the classpath
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.Preconditions.condition(Preconditions.java:296)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.<init>(DefaultLauncher.java:48)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherFactory.create(LauncherFactory.java:105)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherFactory.create(LauncherFactory.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:97)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
    ... 18 more
```

So, what is wrong with my configuration and how do I make this thing work with this gradle version?

Comment: 1. What is `spring-test` (artifact and version) 2. Please show us imports in test. 3. Most importantly: do you happen to have`useJUnitPlatform()` in your build.gradle?

Comment: Updated the question. 1. `spring-test` is 5.3.15. 2. Added in the imports. 3. Yes, `useJUnitPlatform()` is present.

Answer (score 5):

You have a mix of JUnit5 and JUnit4, which requires extra attention to configuration.

To explain:

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

`useJUnitPlatform` instructs Gradle to use Junit5 execution engines.

- Jupiter engine for JUnit5 tests
- Vintage engine for JUnit4 tests

The engine must be present on runtime classpath for tests.

In particular, the following config is invalid:

```
// Invalid config
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

You enable JUnit5 engine usage, but don't include any as dependency. **This is precisely what happened in your build config**

This results in an exception you can see in your stack trace:

```
Caused by: org.junit.platform.commons.PreconditionViolationException: Cannot create Launcher without at least one TestEngine; consider adding an engine implementation JAR to the classpath
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.Preconditions.condition(Preconditions.java:296)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.<init>(DefaultLauncher.java:48)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherFactory.create(LauncherFactory.java:105)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherFactory.create(LauncherFactory.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:97)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
```

Now you have two options:

**Option 1: Use JUnit4 only**

- remove `useJUnitPlatform()`
- only use JUnit4 tests

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
}
```

**Option 2: Use JUnit5 platform and vintage engine**

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation "junit:junit:4.13.2"
    testRuntimeOnly "org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.7.0"
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

In the long run, consider:

- Moving to JUnit5 (you can mix Junit4 and JUnit5 tests if you use Junit Platform and include both engines). See [Migrating from JUnit 4](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#migrating-from-junit4)
- dropping PowerMock - Mockito is getting more and more features, maybe you are in a position to drop this dependency.